# Intellisense not working in Jupyter Notebook in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, intellisense

Intellisense and the coloring of code is no longer working in my Jupyter Notebook in VSCode. It was working perfectly fine before then I reloaded the window(like I have done before without issue) and it doesn't work any more.
[image]
[image]

I tried reloading, resetting the kernel, uninstalling Jupyter, and checking if any other extensions were causing this issue, but nothing seems to work.
I have been stuck on this for so long and I have no idea what could have caused it or how to fix it.

**Update:** I further discovered that this only happens within the specific virtual environment that I am working in. Jupyter works fine outside of this environment.

**Update 2:** The issue seems to happen in any virtual environment, even new ones that I created to test it in.

Comment: If you could find exact steps to reproduce this, that would be great

Comment: I only reloaded the window and cleared cache a few times in quick succession. Maybe this corrupted or reset a config file?

Answer (score 10):

A guess is that the setting of **python.languageServer** was none in your `settings.json`. I  encountered the same problem after an update before.

Add the following codes to your `settings.json`, this works for me:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still giving the same issue.

Comment: Another guess, have you installed the extension of Dependency Analytics? Try to disable it.

Comment: Yea I checked that too but I don't have it installed. And I even uninstalled all other extensions.

Comment: Did you check whether highlight works in `.py` file? If it works, I suggest you installing pre-version of jupyter.

Comment: Yes it works in .py files, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter but that did not work. I will try installing a previous version.

Comment: This problem should be solved in Dec last year according to [this issue in github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6799). I think there is something wrong with your extension or vscode itself. Try to reinstall them one by one may work.

Comment: FWIW, this solution worked for me

Comment: Worked for me on Mac, VSCode Version: 1.85.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

adding "python.languageServer": "Pylance", worked for me.

How to open settings.json :- go to setting in bottom, search autocomplete and then chose python and then click on edit on settings.json

[image]

Comment: After installation of the Pylance extension, I also added the line below in the user settings.json (not sure if this has any impact but it worked for me after restarting vscode).

`"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python.exe"],`

Answer (score 2):

I've been having a similar problem since I upgraded to MacOS Sonoma.  Intellisense worked fine in `.py` files, but didn't work in `.ipynb` files.

I was able to resolve this by closing `vscode`, and then opening it with all extensions disabled.  If you're on a mac, use this command in terminal `code --disable-extensions` or if you're using OhMyZSH, the shortcut is `vscde`.  You can also do it via the command palette in `vscode`.  I used the terminal method.

Once opened, there's no intellisense, obviously.  But `vscode` gave me a prompt to reload with extensions enabled. I clicked that, the window reloaded and I had intellisense working again in my python notebooks.

Comment: This also worked for me on the latest code-insiders, still on MacOS Ventura, using Remote Development extensions. A regular reload, exit+reopen, upgrading versions hadn't helped didn't help.

Comment: Worked for me today with standard VsCode. Started code with `code --disable-extensions`, clicked on Reload with extension and autocomplete is back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"`,
setting `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` to `/path/to/your/venv/lib/python<version>/site-packages` in json settings worked for me to get VS Code's Intellisense working for a Jupyter notebook installation via pip in a virtualenv.  Also, setting the kernel to the running Jupyter server at `localhost:8888` might be required...